# Pure-SQL Technique for Auto-Numbering Rows in Result Set

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm looking for a way to sequentially number rows in a *result set* (not a table).  In essence, I'm starting with a query like the following:

```
SELECT id, name FROM people WHERE name = 'Spiewak'
```

The `id`s are obviously not a true sequence (e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4`).  What I need is another column in the result set which contains these auto-numberings.  I'm willing to use a SQL function if I have to, but I would rather do it without using extensions on the ANSI spec.

Platform is MySQL, but the technique should be cross-platform if at all possible (hence the desire to avoid non-standard extensions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To have a meaningful row number you need to order your results.  Then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT id, name
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people p2 WHERE name='Spiewak' AND p2.id <= p1.id) AS RowNumber
FROM people p1
WHERE name = 'Spiewak'
ORDER BY id
```

Note that the WHERE clause of the sub query needs to match the WHERE clause or the primary key from the main query *and* the ORDER BY of the main query.

SQL Server has the ROW_NUMBER() OVER construct to simplify this, but I don't know if MySQL has anything special to address it.

---

Since my post here was accepted as the answer, I want to also call out Dan Goldstein's response, which is very similar in approach but uses a JOIN instead of a sub query and will often perform better

Comment: That's clever, but the performance must be HORRIBLE.  Not that I'm saying there's a better answer, just shuddering at the O(n^2) of it.

Comment: Wow!  That's very clever.  I didn't even know you could use subqueries to define res fields in that fashion.

Comment: Agreed that performance could be better, but if you're limited to ansi it's what you have to do.  Sometimes people will pre-calculate these results to speed things up.

Comment: Oh, and if your id column (in this case) lines up on a clustered index it may not be _that_ bad.  SQL Server 2000, at least, was smart enough to cache and build on the previous results.

Comment: This solution is ANSI and can perform - however - it's a potential maintenance nightmare problem the ordering has to be strict and can get out of sync of the criteria change.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, there's no "standard" way.

MS SQL Server has row_number(), which MySQL has not.

The simplest way to do this in MySQL is

`SELECT a.*, @num := @num + 1 b from test a, (SELECT @num := 0) d;`

Source: comments in http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/

Answer (score 8):

One idea that is pretty inefficient but is ANSI SQL would be to count the number of rows with a lesser id matching the same criteria. I haven't tested this SQL and it probably won't work, but something like:

```
SELECT id, name, sub.lcount
FROM people outer
JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(id) lcount FROM people WHERE name = 'Spiewak' AND id < outer.id GROUP BY id) sub on outer.id = sub.id
WHERE name = 'Spiewak'
```

Comment: Basically the same as what I posted, but the JOIN will probably be faster than the sub query for most cases.

Comment: Oh, you still need an explicit order by on your outer queury or this may return results ordered differently than the query.

Answer (score 2):

There is no ANSI-standard way to do this of which I am aware.

In SQL Server you have a ROW_NUMBER() function which can be used and in Oracle, there is a ROWNUM pseudo column.

In MySQL, there is [this technique](http://squeejee.com/articles/9-mysql-oracle-rownum)

Comment: He'd probably prefer ROW_NUMBER() to RANK() for this, but as he's using MySQL/Ansi it's a moot point.

Answer (score 2):

This page should give you a standard SQL way of doing it:

https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/returning-a-row-number-in-a-query

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS iterator, t.*
FROM tablename t,(SELECT @i:=0) foo
```

Answer (score 2):

In oracle the only database I know what you would want to do is do a sub select on the data

i.e.

```
select rownum, id , blah, blah
from  (
select id, name FROM people WHERE name = 'Spiewak'
)
```

the basic concept is that the rownum will be evaluated on the result set returned from the inner select.

I hope this might point you to a solution that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I was just now looking for this answer.  I tried Dan Goldstein's query in MySQL, but it didn't work as written because 'outer' is a reserved word.  Then, I noticed that it is still using a sub-query, anyways.

So, I figured out a version using JOIN, but NO sub-query:

```
  SELECT SUM(IF(p1.id > p2.id, 0, 1)) AS `row`, p2.id, p2.name
  FROM people p1 JOIN people p2 ON p1.name = p2.name
  WHERE p1.name = 'Spiewak'
  GROUP BY p2.id
```

This worked for me in MySQL 5.1.  For MySQL, it seems to be enough to GROUP BY p2.id.  An explicit ORDER BY p2.id can be added to the end of the query, but I got the same results, either way.

Answer (score 1):

Recent answer to question but I believe window functions are now standard for ANSI SQL or, at least, most current SQL flavors. Therefore, use the ROW_NUMBER() function.

```
SELECT
    p.ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as 'row_id',
    p.id as 'id',
    p.name as 'name'
FROM
    people p
WHERE
    p.name = 'Spiewak'
```

Comment: Indeed, window functions were introduced to ANSI SQL in 2003. MySQL supports window functions since v8.0 (released in 2018). SQLite since v3.25.0 (also from 2018). "For almost eight years, from 2009 until 2017, PostgreSQL was the only major free open-source product to support SQL window functions. Just a year later, by September 2018, all open-source competitors have caught up…and some even overtook." -- source: https://modern-sql.com/blog/2019-02/postgresql-11