# how to store a *sorted* SELECT result in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

In my projects I often need to store the result of a SELECT in another table (we call this a "resultset"). The reason is to dynamically display a large number of rows in a web application while loading only small chunks as necessary.

Typically, this is done by queries such as this one:

```
SET @counter := 0;
INSERT INTO resultsetdata
  SELECT "12345", @counter:=@counter+1, a.ID
    FROM sometable a
    JOIN bigtable b
      WHERE (a.foo = b.bar)
    ORDER BY a.whatever DESC;
```

The fixed `"12345"` value is just a value to identify the "resultset" as a whole and changes for each query. The second column is a incrementing index counter that is meant to allow direct access to a specific row in the result and the `ID` column references the specific row in the source data table.

When the application needs a certain range of the result I just join `resultsetdata` with the source table to get the detailed data - which is quick as opposed to the `resultsetdata` query above which may take 2-3 seconds to complete (which explains why I need this intermediary table).

The SELECT query itself is not relevant for this question.

`resultsetdata` has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `resultsetdata` (
  `ID`      int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ContIdx` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Value`   int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`ContIdx`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This usually works like a charm but lately we noticed that in *some* cases the ORDER of the result is not correct. This depends on the query itself (*for example, adding `DISTINCT` is a typical cause*), the server version and the data contained in the source tables, so I guess one can say that the **row order is unpredictable** with this method. Probably it depends on internal optimizations.

However, **the problem** is now that I can't think of any alternative solution that gives me the expected result.

Since the resultset can get several thousands of rows, loading all data in memory and then manually `INSERT`ing it is not feasible.

Any suggestions?

---

**EDIT:** For further clarification, have a look at these queries:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (ID INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(ID)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO test (ID) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);

SET @counter:=0;
SELECT "12345", @counter:=@counter+1, ID
  FROM test
  ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

This produces the following result as "expected":

```
+-------+----------------------+----+
| 12345 | @counter:=@counter+1 | ID |
+-------+----------------------+----+
| 12345 |                    1 | 10 |
| 12345 |                    2 |  9 |
| 12345 |                    3 |  8 |
| 12345 |                    4 |  7 |
| 12345 |                    5 |  6 |
| 12345 |                    6 |  5 |
| 12345 |                    7 |  4 |
| 12345 |                    8 |  3 |
| 12345 |                    9 |  2 |
| 12345 |                   10 |  1 |
+-------+----------------------+----+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As said, in **some** cases (I can't provide a testcase here, sorry), this **may** lead to a result similar to this:

```
+-------+----------------------+----+
| 12345 | @counter:=@counter+1 | ID |
+-------+----------------------+----+
| 12345 |                   10 | 10 |
| 12345 |                    9 |  9 |
| 12345 |                    8 |  8 |
| 12345 |                    7 |  7 |
| 12345 |                    6 |  6 |
| 12345 |                    5 |  5 |
| 12345 |                    4 |  4 |
| 12345 |                    3 |  3 |
| 12345 |                    2 |  2 |
| 12345 |                    1 |  1 |
+-------+----------------------+----+
```

I'm not saying this is a MySQL bug and I fully understand that my method currently provides unpredictable results. Still, I don't know how to tweak this to get predictable results.

Comment: How is the order not correct? As in, the final 'id' is not sorted how you want it to be? You allready added a counter, do you mean that counter isn't correctly sorted? How do you select, with a sort on that counter? Anyway, overall, this whole thing feels a bit like a manually implemented cache system. Are you sure you even need this method? Couldn't you faster save your result into some sort of real caching system, or maybe update `sometable` and `bigtable` so this does not take that many seconds?

Comment: Can you provide right `ORDER`ed result and wrong `ORDER`ed one? And your `SELECT` just to be sure.

Comment: I mean that, in certain cases, when executing the `SELECT` without the `INSERT INTO` on the console, you see the `ContIdx` in **decreasing** order. Yeah, this is somewhat *related* to a caching system but I don't think loading tons of data into memory(?) is a better solution. The problem applies to a wide range of queries/tables which contain tons of aquired data, so I have no way to further optimize the SELECT query (ie. I can't do it again and again while the user browses through the data). Besides I need somthing *static* because the tables are continously filled with data.

Comment: That's how a relational database works. Rows in a table are ***not*** sorted (picture them as balls in a basket). The only way to ensure a specific order is to use an `order by`.

Comment: @НЛО: added
@a_horse_with_no_name: correct, but one can *store* the order of rows by using a unique, incrementing index, which would be `ContIdx` in my case.

Comment: Try to `AUTOINCREMENT` your `ContIdx` instead of manually `@counter:=@counter+1` and rely on DB engine to assign counters.

Comment: @НЛО: good idea, but I see two problems: first, ContIdx would not start at 1 (I could work around this, but it means quite some work). Second, `ContIdx` could have "holes" for a single "resultset" (*bad, since I need to access specific rows of the result afterwards*) when two INSERTing queries run at the same time - unless I use a transaction or some sort of locking (bad performance-wise). A workaround for the holes woule be using `SELECT ... ORDER BY ContIDX LIMIT a,b` when accessing data. Could work, but I really hope there is a simpler solution :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could wrap the select into another select:

```
SET @counter := 0;

INSERT INTO resultsetdata
  SELECT *, @counter := @counter + 1
  FROM (
      SELECT "12345", a.ID
      FROM sometable a
      JOIN bigtable  b
      WHERE a.foo = b.bar
      ORDER BY a.whatever DESC
  ) AS tmp
```

... but you are still at the mercy of the dumbness of MySQL's optimizer.

That's all I found about this topic, but I couln't find a hard guarantee:

[Pure-SQL Technique for Auto-Numbering Rows in Result Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202245/pure-sql-technique-for-auto-numbering-rows-in-result-set)

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/27/simulating-the-sql-row_number-function/

Comment: Simple and it works. Great :-) I don't expect that the optimizer will try to optimize the outer SELECT, though (fingers crossed).

Comment: Maybe you should find some explanation from real experts, like Quassnoi @ http://explainextended.com/ or http://www.xaprb.com/ 's older blog entries, or whatever you find :)

Answer (score 3):

This is because the order that records are sorted when they are inserted is unrelated to the order when you retrieve them.

When you retrieve them a query plan will be created. If no ORDER BY is specified in your SELECT statement then the order will depend on the query plan produced. This is why it is unpredictable and adding DISTINCT can change the order.

The solution is to store enough data that you can retrieve them in the correct order using an ORDER BY clause. In your case you have ordered your data by a.whatever. Can a.whatever be stored in resultsetdata? If so then you can read the records out in the correct order.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I can't store `a.whatever` in `resultsetdata` because I may also use `ORDER BY` on multiple columns and the type of the sorted columns is not always the same. Besides of that this is part of a framework that even has no clue what the real query is about.