# Autonumbering Rows in mysql view in cycles

Tags: mysql, view, autonumber

Hi I am trying to achieve rows auto numbering in cycles in a mysql view.
I did start with [Pure-SQL Technique for Auto-Numbering Rows in Result Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202245/pure-sql-technique-for-auto-numbering-rows-in-result-set) and got it to work. Then I tried tweaking it and got ALMOST there.... and now I am stuMainmped

the view lists dogs (CaneID) and their ascendants(AvoID). What I would like to achieve is for the numbering to resart every time the main dog (CaneID) changes so I would have each ascendant belonging to a dog number from 1 on.

So far it is working only for the first dog, the following are still numbered in sequence but do not start from 1.

This is my view query:

```
SELECT
`avi1`.`CaneID`,
`avi1`.`Cane`,
`avi1`.`PedPos`,
`avi1`.`AvoID`,
`avi1`.`Avo`,
`avi1`.`Ripetuto`,
(
    SELECT
        count(0)
    FROM
        `v_avi_ripetuti` `Avi2`
    WHERE
        (
             (`avi2`.`Ripetuto` > 1)
            AND (`avi2`.`CaneID` <= `avi1`.`CaneID`)
            AND (`avi2`.`AvoID` <= `avi1`.`AvoID`)

        )
    ORDER BY
        `avi2`.`CaneID`,
        `avi2`.`AvoID`
) AS `RowNumber`
FROM
`v_avi_ripetuti` `Avi1`
WHERE
(`avi1`.`Ripetuto` > 1)
ORDER BY
`avi1`.`CaneID`,
`avi1`.`AvoID`
```

What I am getting at this point is:

```
CaneID  Cane         AvoID  Avo                             RowNumber
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2       Antigua      472    Anika v. Stammhaus Eike         1
2       Antigua      527    Britta v.d. Römerlinde          2
2       Antigua      642    Ares v. Nettenberg              3
2       Antigua      657    Carmen v. Westfalenzwinger      4
2       Antigua      658    Leu v. Stammhaus Eike           5
2       Antigua      684    Chipsy v. Theresienhof          6
2       Antigua      1662   Astrit v.d. Burrlinde           7
-----------------------> New Main dog<-------------------------------
3       Ambra Gaya   472    Anika v. Stammhaus Eike         2
3       Ambra Gaya   657    Carmen v. Westfalenzwinger      6
3       Ambra Gaya   658    Leu v. Stammhaus Eike           8
3       Ambra Gaya   684    Chipsy v. Theresienhof          10
3       Ambra Gaya   718    Leo v. guten Löwen              11
3       Ambra Gaya   1022   Zara v. Ratibor u. Corvey       12
3       Ambra Gaya   1024   Ruth v. Ratibor u. Corvey       13
3       Ambra Gaya   1050   Dunja v. Hofoldinger Forst      14
3       Ambra Gaya   1200   Icksle v. Ratibor u. Corvey     15
3       Ambra Gaya   1227   Troldegaards Tanja              16
3       Ambra Gaya   1228   Anemone v. Ratibor u. Corvey    17
-----------------------> New Main dog<-------------------------------
3371    Always Habit 600    Absinthe v. Kallenberg          4
3371    Always Habit 750    Mathoaka's Relaxing Boy         13
3371    Always Habit 2560   Leijonamielen Luvaton Lyyli     21
```

I am very new to mysql (installed it a week ago) and trying very hard to leave access behind....please be patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I DID IT!!!!!!!
I used the function SUM() instead of COUNT().
This is my mysql View Code in case someone else can use it:

```
SELECT
`avi1`.`CaneID`,
`avi1`.`Cane`,
`avi1`.`PedPos`,
`avi1`.`AvoID`,
`avi1`.`Avo`,
`avi1`.`Ripetuto`,
(
    SELECT
        sum(

            IF (
                (
                    (
                        `avi2`.`CaneID` = `avi1`.`CaneID`
                    )
                    AND (`avi2`.`AvoID` <= `avi1`.`AvoID`)
                ),
                1,
                0
            )
        )
    FROM
        `v_avi_ripetuti` `Avi2`
    WHERE
        (`avi2`.`Ripetuto` > 1)
) AS `NumRiga`
  FROM
`v_avi_ripetuti` `Avi1`
 WHERE
(`avi1`.`Ripetuto` > 1)
```

and this gives me the desired result of:

```
 CaneID  Cane         AvoID  Avo                             RowNumber
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 2       Antigua      472    Anika v. Stammhaus Eike         1
 2       Antigua      527    Britta v.d. Römerlinde          2
 2       Antigua      642    Ares v. Nettenberg              3
 2       Antigua      657    Carmen v. Westfalenzwinger      4
 2       Antigua      658    Leu v. Stammhaus Eike           5
 2       Antigua      684    Chipsy v. Theresienhof          6
 2       Antigua      1662   Astrit v.d. Burrlinde           7
 -----------------------> New Main dog<-------------------------------
 3       Ambra Gaya   472    Anika v. Stammhaus Eike         1
 3       Ambra Gaya   657    Carmen v. Westfalenzwinger      2
 3       Ambra Gaya   658    Leu v. Stammhaus Eike           3
 3       Ambra Gaya   684    Chipsy v. Theresienhof          4
 3       Ambra Gaya   718    Leo v. guten Löwen              5
 3       Ambra Gaya   1022   Zara v. Ratibor u. Corvey       6
 3       Ambra Gaya   1024   Ruth v. Ratibor u. Corvey       7
 3       Ambra Gaya   1050   Dunja v. Hofoldinger Forst      8
 3       Ambra Gaya   1200   Icksle v. Ratibor u. Corvey     9
 3       Ambra Gaya   1227   Troldegaards Tanja              10
 3       Ambra Gaya   1228   Anemone v. Ratibor u. Corvey    11
 -----------------------> New Main dog<-------------------------------
 3371    Always Habit 600    Absinthe v. Kallenberg          1
 3371    Always Habit 750    Mathoaka's Relaxing Boy         2
 3371    Always Habit 2560   Leijonamielen Luvaton Lyyli     3
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want things ordered as they are in the results, first by `CaneId` and then by `AvoId`. If so, the correct subquery is:

```
(SELECT count(*)
 FROM v_avi_ripetuti` `Avi2`
  WHERE `avi2`.`Ripetuto` > 1 AND
        (`avi2`.`CaneID` < `avi1`.`CaneID` or
          `avi2`.`CaneID` = `avi1`.`CaneID` and avi2`.`AvoID` <= `avi1`.`AvoID`
        )
) AS `RowNumber`
```

In addition to fixing the `where` clause, I also removed the `order by`, because it is irrelevant in the subquery.  I also changed `count(0)` to `count(*)`.  These are equivalent, but `count(0)` looks awkward to me.

Comment: what I would like to achieve is that the numbering restarts for every main dog like:                                                             
     2       Antigua      472    Anika               1
     2       Antigua      527    Britta              2
     2       Antigua      642    Ares                3
     2       Antigua      657    Carmen              4
     3       Ambra Gaya   472    Anika               1
     3       Ambra Gaya   657    Carmen              2
     3371    Always Habit 600    Absinthe            1
     3371    Always Habit 750    Mathoaka's          2

Comment: Maybe I was not too clear in asking the question ...my English is by no means excellent, what I wanted to achieve was a sort of "cycling" so that each new dog had its ascendants numbered starting from 1 on. Your solution works beautifully for having an "unbroken" list though so I am keeping that in mind too ;-) –